# How to send method name as parameter

Tags: c#, events

I want to create some engine for monogame in c#. My engine have to include button. I want to do it with events. Basically I have it done, but I want to improve it and there began my problems.

```
  class Button : Component
  {
    ....
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Click;
    public void OnClick()
    {
        if (MousePressed() && Click != null)
        {
            Click(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
  }
```

and when I want to add Click event I have to do it in another class:

```
_buttnon.Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Method);
_buttnon.OnClick();
```

It works nice, but I want to do it in following way:

```
_button.RegisterClickEvent(Method);
```

so I added to the Button class code below:

```
 public void RegisterClickEvent(XXX method) {
        Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(method);
 }
```

I absolutely have no idea what I have to replace the XXX. I tried:

```
 public void RegisterClickEvent(void(object, EventArgs)method) {
        Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(method);
 }
```

but it is not working. I tried to search for something on Google, but I do not know what I look for.

Comment: "I absolutely have no idea what I have to replace the XXX". `EventHandler<EventArgs>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use a delegate:

```
  public void RegisterClickEvent(EventHandler<EventArgs> method)
  {
    Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(method);
  }
```

or

```
  public void RegisterClickEvent(EventHandler method)
  {
    Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(method);
  }
```

This works (at least in VS2015, perhaps there is another way in previous (before 2010, since there were some changes with delegates).

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an [*action*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx), something like this:

```
public void RegisterClickEvent(Action<object, EventArgs> method) 
{
    Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(method);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of constructor of `EventHandler<EventArgs>` get `EventHandler<EventArgs>` as an argument you can use code below:

```
public void RegisterClickEvent(EventHandler<EventArgs> method)
{
    Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(method);
}

...
RegisterClickEvent(Method);
```

Comment: You should note that this won't work: RegisterClickEvent is static but Click isn't.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath thank you for fix. It was bad copy-paste from my sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

`Method` is a method group. A method group doesn't have a type, it can however be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type. If you specify a delegate as a method parameter, you can invoke the method with a method group as argument and it will be implicitly converted.

Translating all this to your code, it would be

```
public void RegisterClickEvent(EventHandler<EventArgs> handler) 
{
    Click += handler;
}
```

If the signature of `Method` is compatible with `EventHandler<EventArgs>` delegate, you can use it as

```
_button.RegisterClickEvent(Method);
```

Which will is equivalent to

```
_button.RegisterClickEvent(new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Method));
```

It doesn't really add any extra functionality to the built-in `+=` operator for events.